# WIFI connection BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I have a code which listens for connecting or disconnecting to a hotspot or a wifi , I have two Logs in the BroadCastReceiver my problem is when I connect to a wifi or disconnect from a wifi it gives me a lot of Logs can you help me why this is happening. here is my code

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
package com.example.amire.yadavar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class IsWifiConnectedBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) Log.d("WIFI is Connected to", wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID());
        else if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) Log.d("WIFI not-Connected to",wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".IsWifiConnectedBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**The Logs from one connecting**

```
08-27 20:37:07.550 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.558 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.561 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.565 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.569 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.576 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.925 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.928 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.941 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.947 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:07.956 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:08.150 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
08-27 20:37:08.158 4665-4665/com.example.amire.yadavar D/WIFI is Connected to: "HUAWEI Y330-U01"
```

**Thanks For Your Comments.**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different broadcast `Intent`s with different ACTIONs and with different data. You should log all the data in the `Intent`, including all the "extras". This gives you a lot of fine-grained information. If you don't want all this fine-grained information, you can decide to react on `Intent`s with the specific data that you are looking for and ignore the rest.